# Test on empty value universal for all types

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a solution for testing if a value of any type is empty (or default). I.e. some kind of method on `Any` that tests if a `String` instance is equal to `""`, an `Int` - to `0`, a `Float` - to `0f`, a `Boolean` - to `false`, a `List` contains no items and so on for other types. Primarilly I'm interested whether some solution already exists in the standard library and if not how you would implement it. I believe this could be useful and if it doesn't exist in the standard library it should be suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Zero`](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/Zero.scala.html) type-class from Scalaz.

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> def isEmpty[A : Zero](value: A) = value == mzero[A]
isEmpty: [A](value: A)(implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Zero[A])Boolean

scala> isEmpty("")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty(List())
res1: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty(false)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty("O HAI")
res3: Boolean = false
```

[Link to a blog post](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.com/2011/08/emulating-cs-default-keyword-in-scala.html) of mine on a related topic.

Comment: Great blog post! Why do you suggest the Scalaz' based solution?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: You don't need to use Scalaz. I have included a link to `Zero.scala` in Scalaz, and as you can see it's trivial to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing around things of type T, you could pass around things of type Option[T], wrapping all valid things of type T, like so

```
val thing = 1
val thingOption = Some(thing)
```

and storing all invalid data as Nones, like so

```
val thingOption = None
```

Then, if you want to make a decision based on the value of thingOption, you can do it like this

```
thingOption match {
    case None    => // Whatever you want to do with defaults
    case Some(x) => // Whatever you want to do with 'thing' if it isn't a default
}
```

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, I propose an experiment, put a reminder for a year from now in your calendar with a link to your question. When the reminder pops up, go back to this answer and your comment and see if you still feel the same.

Comment: @huynhjl I know very well about the benefits of the `Option` over `null` approach, but with my remark I was pointing out that this suggestion had nothing to do with the current question. There's a pretty solid border between `null` and `""` or `0`

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, but is highly relevant. Testing if a value is "zero-esque" is often a sign that you should be using Options instead.